# How to obtain three level model data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

**Updated**

User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens, HasRoles;

    const MALE = 'male';
    const FEMALE = 'female';

    protected $guard_name = 'sanctum';


    public function educationalBackgrounds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Users\EducationalBackground", "user_id");
    }

    public function seminars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Users\Seminar", "user_id");
    }
}
```

I have child table `EducationalBackground` which is related to User table

```
class EducationalBackground extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users.educational_backgrounds';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'studies_type',
        'year',
        'course',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function educationalAwards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Users\EducationalAward", "educational_background_id");
    }
}
```

And a third table that i want to access the `award` field

```
class EducationalAward extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users.educational_awards';
    protected $fillable = [
        'educational_background_id',
        'award',
        'photo',
    ];

    public function educationalBackground()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users\EducationalBackground', 'educational_background_id');
    }
}
```

I have api get route here

```
Route::get('/educational-background/{id}', [UserProfileController::class, 'getEducationalBackground']);
```

Here is my api method it works fine. But i want to go deeper and access the data of third table.

```
public function getEducationalBackground($id) 
    {
        $educationalBackground = EducationalBackground::with('user')->where('user_id', $id)->get();

        return response()->json($educationalBackground, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not really grasping the concept of relations yet. Also, I'd advise you to look into route model binding :) What you basically want to be doing is:

```
public function getEducationalBackground($id) 
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return $user->educationalBackgrounds()->with('educationalAwards')->get();
}
```

Also, when you're pretty sure that whenever you want to use backgrounds, you also want to use the awards, you can add the `with(...)` to the model definition like so:

```
class EducationalBackground extends Model
{
    ...
    protected $with = ['educationalAwards'];
}
```

That way, you can simplify your controller method to:

```
public function getEducationalBackground($id) 
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return $user->educationalBackgrounds;
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answering. Forgot to mention that im using it as api so i need to return response()->json($educationalBackground, 200);. Sorry definitely my fault i've been scratching my head with this one.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual http response when using `return response()->json($var, 200)` and `return $var`? My guess is that they're functionally equivalent. Also, the names of your methods suggest you are returning 1 background, but it's going to be 0 or more

Comment: Yes you're right it gives 1 data and 200 status. I have tried the code it gives message: "Call to undefined method App\\Models\\User::educationalAwards()".

Comment: Can you add your user model definition? Also, maybe I've misunderstood your data structure: is it true a user has 0 or more awards, and these awards belong to a background? Or does a user have 0 or more backgrounds, and these backgrounds have 0 or more awards?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i'll update the post. Give me a sec

Comment: user have 0 or more backgrounds, and these backgrounds have 0 or more awards. I have updated the post bro. My bad

Comment: I've updated my answer as well :)

Comment: Tried and tested works 100%. Thank you so much